# BFI_Thumb, can't get to work outside of wordpress functions

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I have several sites using BFI thumb and I have no issues, I am trying to use BFI thumb on a non featured image and it is not resizing, the image is being shown but without any actions being applied, I have spent hours on this now and just can't figure it out, please see below.

```
<?php $params = array( 'width' => 100 );
echo "<img src='" . bfi_thumb( "wp-content/themes/ncpi/images/services/officerefurbishment.jpg", $params ) . "'/>"; ?>
```

The page can be seen at http://new.ncpi.london/services

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the image you posted are being cut, where do you see your issue? In the detailed page I see problems with thumbs but not in the provided link.

Comment: Thanks, they are not being cut, they are still the original size but not being shown due to the container, have moved them outside of the original boxes now so you can see clearer.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still can't figure out what is wrong...